# brew install coreutils error for 10.12.6 OSX

Tags: macos, homebrew, gnu-coreutils

in OSX install error,

```
brew install coreutils

Error: coreutils: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:73: syntax error, unexpected << def caveats; <<~EOS

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:77: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:77: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:79: dynamic constant assignment
    PATH="#{opt_libexec}/gnubin:$PATH"
         ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:81: dynamic constant assignment
Additionally, you can access their man pag...
             ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:81: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
Additionally, you can access their man pages with ...
                     ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:82: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
the "gnuman" directory to your MANPATH from your bashrc as well:
                      ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:82: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/coreutils.rb:84: dynamic constant assignment
    MANPATH="#{opt_libexec}/gnuman:$MANPATH"`
```

What is the reason?
  Please help me thanks

Comment: What is your homebrew version? Have you tried to update the `homebrew` ? And what is your Mac OS X version?

Comment: @Raptor updated homebrew ,The problem has been solved, Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There is a closed issue on GitHub about this: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3353

According to that discussion, this resolves the error:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/.git
brew update
brew config
```

I have not tested this myself.

Comment: install success,Thank you very much!